# How to get a list of elements from the lower triangular matrix

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8

I am new to Mathematica.

I have a lower triangular matrix defined as follow

`A = Table[If[i > j, Subscript[a, i, j], 0], {i, s}, {j, s}];`

I would like to the lower triangular elements in a list. For example, when `s = 2`, the list would contain `listOfElement = {a_{2,1}}` and for `s = 3`, `listOfElement = {a_{2,1},a_{3,1},a_{3,2}}`

How can I do this in Mathematica?

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/99390/5478

Comment: @Kuba extraction of the elements in the linked question seems to be antidiagonal-wise, while OP seems to be interested in "column-wise" extraction...

Comment: you can just do this: `Select[Flatten@A, # =!= 0 &]` , assuming there are no explicit zeros in the lower triangular part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for example this

```
A = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3, 3}];
MatrixForm[A]
M = First[Dimensions[A]];
Flatten[A[[# + 1 ;;, #]] & /@ Range[M - 1]]
```

produces:

```
(0.586886   0.968229    0.543306
 0.107212   0.0492116   0.103052
 0.0569797  0.429895    0.70289
)

{0.107212,0.0569797,0.429895}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Pick` together with a selection matrix:

```
selectionMatrix = LowerTriangularize[ConstantArray[1, {s, s}], -1]
```

`selectionMatrix` is now a lower triangular matrix with ones where you want to `Pick` elements in `A`. You then get the elements of `A` like this:

```
listOfElements = Flatten @ Pick[A, selectionMatrix, 1]
```

*edit*: Make sure you define `s`, of course.